# UITableView cell text is not showing xml data in iPhone application development

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsxmlparser

I am newer in iPhone application development. I want to find out why tableview cell is not showing data. I tried a lot of ways. I am giving my code below.

Note that I am seeing data at my console which is coming from XML file but it's not displaying in UITableView cell.

```
    
    @synthesize newsTable;
    @synthesize  activityIndicator; 
    @synthesize rssParser; 
    @synthesize  stories;   
    @synthesize  item;
    @synthesize  currentElement; 
    @synthesize  currentTitle, currentDate, currentSummary, currentLink;


    // The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
    /*
    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization.
        }
        return self;
    }
    */

    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark Parsing

    // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
    }


    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
    { 
        [super viewDidAppear:animated]; 
        if ([stories count] == 0) { 
            NSString * path = @"http://icms7.bitmascot.com:8080/webcommander2.0S2/rest/services/catalogue/getAllDummyCategoryProduct"; 
            [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path]; 
        } 
        cellSize = CGSizeMake([newsTable bounds].size.width, 60); 
    }


    - (void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL 
    { 
        stories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
        //you must then convert the path to a proper NSURL or it won't work 
        NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL]; 
        // here, for some reason you have to use NSClassFromString when trying to alloc NSXMLParser, otherwise you will get an object not found error 
        // this may be necessary only for the toolchain 
        rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL]; 
        // Set self as the delegate of the parser so that it will receive the parser delegate methods callbacks. 
        [rssParser setDelegate:self]; 
        // Depending on the XML document you're parsing, you may want to enable these features of NSXMLParser. 
        [rssParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO]; 
        [rssParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO]; 
        [rssParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO]; 
        [rssParser parse];
    }

    - (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
        { 
            NSLog(@"found file and started parsing"); 
        } 
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError 
        { 
            NSString * errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unable to download story feed from web site (Error code %i )", [parseError code]]; 
            NSLog(@"error parsing XML: %@", errorString); 
            UIAlertView * errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error loading content" message:errorString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]; 
            [errorAlert show]; 
        } 
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{ 
        NSLog(@"found this element: %@", elementName); 
        currentElement = [elementName copy]; 
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ProductData"]) 
        { 
            // clear out our story item caches... 
            item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 
            currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; 
            currentDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; 
            currentSummary = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; 
            currentLink = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; 
        }
    } 
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{ 
        //NSLog(@"ended element: %@", elementName); 
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ProductData"]) 
            { // save values to an item, then store that item into the array... 
                [item setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"id"]; 
                [item setObject:currentLink forKey:@"productNumber"]; 
                [item setObject:currentSummary forKey:@"name"]; 
                [item setObject:currentDate forKey:@"dateCreated"]; 
                [stories addObject:[item copy]];
                NSLog(@"adding story: %@", currentTitle); 
            } 
    } 
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{ 
        NSLog(@"found characters: %@", string); 
        // save the characters for the current item... 
        if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"ProductData"]) 
            { 
                [currentTitle appendString:string]; 
            } 
        else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"id"]) 
            { 
                [currentLink appendString:string]; 
            } 
        else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"ProductNumber"]) 
        { 
            [currentSummary appendString:string]; 
        } 
        else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"dateCreatrd"]) 
        { 
            [currentDate appendString:string]; 
        } 
    } 
    - (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser { 
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating]; 
        [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview]; 
        NSLog(@"all done!"); 
        NSLog(@"stories array has %d items", [stories count]);
        NSLog(@"data in stories: %@",[stories description]);
        [newsTable reloadData]; 
    }


    #pragma mark tableView


    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [stories count];
    }

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
    {
        return 1;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 

        static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier"; 
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier]; 
        if (cell == nil) 
        { 

            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier: MyIdentifier];

        } 

        // Set up the cell 
        int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1]; 
        //[cell setText:[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"]];
        //[cell setLabelText:[[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] objectForKey: @"ProductData"]];
        //[cell setText:[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex]];
        cell.textLabel.text = [stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex];
        NSLog(@"%@ ",cell.textLabel.text);

        //cell.detailTextLabel.text = [stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell; 
    }


    /*
    - (void)setLabelText:(NSString *)_text{
        UILabel *cellText;
        cellText.text= _text;
        [cellText sizeToFit];
    }
    */
    /*
    // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
        // Return YES for supported orientations.
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }
    */

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

        // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
    }

    - (void)viewDidUnload {
        [super viewDidUnload];
        // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
        // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    }


    - (void)dealloc { 
            [currentElement release]; 
            [rssParser release]; 
            [stories release];
            [item release]; 
            [currentTitle release];
            [currentDate release]; 
            [currentSummary release]; 
            [currentLink release]; 
            [super dealloc]; 
        }


    @end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set value of property `textLabel`, not `detailedTextLabel` :

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] valueForKey:@"productNumber"];
```

Also try to create `cell` using predefined styles:

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier: MyIdentifier];
```

Comment: sorry bro now app is crashing.

Comment: Sorry little mistake app is not crashing...app is being unable to retrieve data from xml file                                      [Session started at 2011-10-06 12:25:03 +0600.]
2011-10-06 12:26:05.897 cmsCommander[1689:207] error parsing XML: Unable to download story feed from web site (Error code 5 )

Comment: `cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];` i am using this for making cell and `int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];` using this for indexPath and `cell.detailTextLabel.text = [stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex];
 NSLog(@"%@ ",cell.detailTextLabel.text);` using this for celltext now app can download the value and can display in the console but cell is being empty and one more thing at that time `NSLog(@"%@ ",cell.detailTextLabel.text);` printing `null` at console.

Comment: Crashing.....2011-10-06 12:54:39.111 cmsCommander[1859:207] -[__NSCFDictionary isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b2afd0
2011-10-06 12:54:39.114 cmsCommander[1859:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b2afd0'

Comment: i have updated my above code.now please anyhow solve it,its really urgent...thank you for helping

Comment: I don't see any changes.. replace `cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];` with `cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier: MyIdentifier];`

Comment: i have changed the code again now tell me..i have run the code again and again...continuosly its crashing.

Comment: Does `NSLog(@"%@ ",cell.textLabel.text);` printing something?

Comment: I've found the problem: replace `cell.textLabel.text = [stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex];` with `cell.textLabel.text = [[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] valueForKey:@"productNumber"];`

Comment: sorry bro `NSLog(@"%@ ",cell.textLabel.text);` does not printing anything.before that app is crashing.

Comment: Have your looked at my previous comment?

Comment: dont be angry bro...still now its not woking using your previous comment.now app is not crashing but it's becoming unable to retrieve data not only in tableview but also in console. and showing that 2011-10-06 13:28:53.195 cmsCommander[2215:207] error parsing XML: Unable to download story feed from web site (Error code 5 )

Comment: but NOTE THAT: when i am using previous cell making sys then data is being retrieve and displaying.

Answer (score 1):

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex];
```

replace above statement with belo wstatement iy will work i think

```
 cell.detailTextLabel.text = [stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: change  UITableViewCell initialization as Nekto said

Comment: Sorry now app is crashing using Nekto's solution.

Comment: your cellForRowAtIndexPath calling or not

Comment: so problem with you cellForRowAtIndexPath code but if you want detailTextLabel you should initialize table as said  Nekto. k

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving,

```
int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1]; 
//[cell setText:[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"]];
//[cell setLabelText:[[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] objectForKey: @"ProductData"]];
//[cell setText:[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex]];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex];
```

try this code:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

before that ,just check your array(stories)having content?

Thank You..

Comment: At first thanks for response.i tried your solution but still now its not working and i have checked stories has content which i can see in console.but its not displaying in cell

Answer (score 1):

To make a cell you should use

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
```

method. By default the **detailTextLabel** is not visible in the cell.
Try to use other styles - UITableViewCellStyleValue1, for example.